# Many to Many Relationship return trying to get property 'books' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to displaying the book a user has favorited, so I think many to many relationships will solve it. So I have 3 tables

1. Users Table
2. Books Table
3. Favorite Table

The Favorite table is the pivot table

```
    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the `User Model`

```
public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

In the `Book Model`

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

In my Favorite Model

```
public function book ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}
```

I was able to save to Favorite Column like this

```
    public function favorite($id)
    {
        Favorite::create([
            'book_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', "You Favorite a Book");

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

But I am  trying to show the Books Favorited

```
public function mylibrary(){
    $user = Auth::user()->books;
  //  dd($user);
   return view('library', compact('user'));
}
```

In my view, I have this

```
              @foreach($user->books as $mybook)
                 ...
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <p class="authorone">{{ $mybook->author->name }}</p>
                  <h1 class="book-title">{ $mybook -> title }}</h1>
                </div>

            @endforeach
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` can return null ... are you sure you are actually saving a value for `user_id` for the `Favorite` you are saving?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The user_id saves to my favorites database.

Comment: also no where have you defined a Many to Many relationship

Comment: try to edit `hasMany` to `belongsToMany`

Comment: @Joseph on which model please?

Comment: @xtremeCODE booth of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way

My view

```
                @forelse ($user->favorites as $mybook)
                  <p class="authorone">{{ $mybook ->book->author-> name }}</p>
                  <h1 class="book-title">{{ $mybook ->book-> name }}</h1>
                @empty
                <h2>You haven't Favorited any book</h2>
                <div class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ route('#') }}" class="return-button">Return To</a>
              </div>
            @endforelse
```

I added this to my user model

```
public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}

public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

My controller

```
public function mylibrary(){
   return view('library', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `Auth::user()->books` to your view, not `Auth::user()`. You are not passing the `User`.

In the view you are then trying to use that value as an object:

```
@foreach ($user->books as $mybook)
```

`Auth::user()->books` is most likely returning `null` since it is not a relation method or an attribute (most likely).

You probably want to pass the `User` to your view:

```
view(..., ['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

Then you would want to access the correct dynamic property for the relationship you want since you aren't showing a `books` relationship on `User`.

---

Your model relationships could use a better setup. There is no Many to Many setup here and you don't need to define a model for the pivot, you are actually avoiding the Many to Many by doing this.

Models:

```
class User
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'favorites');
    }
}

class Book
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favorites');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function favorite($id)
{
    Auth::user()->books()->attach($id);
    ...
}

public function mylibrary()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->load('books.author');

    return view('library', compact('user'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($user->books as $mybook)
    ...
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <p class="authorone">{{ $mybook->author->name }}</p>
      <h1 class="book-title">{{ $mybook->title }}</h1>
    </div>
@endforeach
```